# R connections to Snowflake produce verbose output

Tags: r, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

After a system update some R-functions that are used to connect to Snowflake are producing pages of console output containing connection information:

[Example: first lines of output, followed by lots more](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4W08.png)

Some example functions where the error occurs:

```
source()
dbGetQuery()
dbConnect()
```

I already tried calling the functions arguments (e.g. `verbose=false, echo=false` ...) and changing the global settings. I was not able to reset the console output to what I was used to see:

A simple confirmation running the code (connection) successfully.

Comment: What driver/connector are you using with R to connect to Snowflake?

Comment: I am using the ODBC SnowflakeDSIIDriver (64-Bit) from doc.snowflake.com on a windows system.

Comment: The logging information from the screenshot you added is the default logging in ODBC driver (INFO level). But this should be written to the ODBC log file unless your R program is redirecting output to console rather than a file.